# @html.dropdownlistfor not showing selected value on binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

i m binding a `dropdownlist` in `asp.net mvc 4` before binding i mark a value as selected but when the view is shown dropdown is binded but selected value is not selected

```
List<SelectListItem> citylist = new List<SelectListItem>();
var status = (DataSet)_rtmi_repo.GetCity(ref BaseObject);
foreach (DataRow v in status.Tables[0].Rows)
{
if (v["CODE"].ToString() == selectedval)
{
citylist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = v["CODE"].ToString(), Value = v["CODE"].ToString(), Selected = true });
}
else
{
citylist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = v["CODE"].ToString(), Value = v["CODE"].ToString() });
}
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@{var ddl = (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Location;}
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Location,ddl , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

even in ddl it show the selected true but after binding it always selects first value in list as selected

also created the filddle but here it works fine
["Example FIDDLE"](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1TMXMf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `viewbag` name same as the `model` property name, then the selected option will not be set to the `DropDownListFor`.